# How to index only verified values in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, typegoose

I am going to write a Cards model for payments. However, I am going to index and make unique only verified cards. Cards model has attribute:status. It can be verified or unverified. First, I wrote partialFilterExpression using typegoose. However it is not indexing only verified values

```js
@index(
    {
        number: 1
    },
    {
        unique: true,
        name: 'number',
        background: true,
        partialFilterExpression:{
            is_deleted:false,
            completely_deleted:false,
            status:"verified"
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: Can you please describe your problem in more detail?

Comment: I am facing this issue because anyone can enter card details but with no verification, it should not be unique for user. Because card holder can be another person and when he enter his card details, it says "there is another card like this"